# How to query all term and order DESC

Tags: wordpress

I want to show post have taxonomy tag_year and order DESC but my code not to show

```
$term = get_terms('tag_year');
$query_year = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'tax_query'     =>  array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' =>  'tag_year',
            'field'    =>  'slug',
            'terms'    =>  $term->slug,
        ),
    ),
    'order' =>  'DESC'
);
$query = new WP_Query($query_year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$terms  = get_terms('tag_year');
tax_map = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $tax_map[] = $term->slug;
}
$query_year = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'tax_query'     =>  array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' =>  'tag_year',
            'field'    =>  'slug',
            'terms'    =>  $tax_map,
            'operator' =>  'IN',
        ),
    ),
    'order' =>  'DESC'
);
$query = new WP_Query($query_year);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('your_term_name');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'career',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'your_term_name',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
'order' => DESC
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts())
     { ?>
        <h2><?php echo $custom_term->name.</h2>

       <?php  while($loop->have_posts())
                { $loop->the_post(); ?>
                  <h2> <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title()?></a></h2><br>
                  <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
        <?php 
                }
     }
}
```